# check tow fields values in sharepoint validation settings

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, calculated-column-formula, validation

I have a form to create a task and the user can edit it after manager approve it,
I don't want to allow the user to submit after approval if field [Task Status]="Waiting on someone else" or field [Ext. Due Date] not blank. the user must write Reason for delay in [Reason for the delay] field to submit it if [Task Status]="Waiting on someone else" or field [Ext. Due Date] not blank.

I have tried this formula and it doesn't work for me:

```
=OR(([Task Status]="Waiting on someone else",(NOT(ISBLANK([Ext. Due Date])))),IF([Reason for the delay]<>"",TRUE,FALSE),TRUE)
```

Any help?

Comment: Are you getting any syntax error or the formula logic is not working for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using below formula:

```
=IF(OR([Task Status]="Waiting on someone else",NOT(ISBLANK([Ext. Due Date]))), IF([Reason for the delay]="",FALSE,TRUE), TRUE)
```

**Note**:

1. Sometimes comma(`,`) does not work in formula (I am not sure but it is based on something language or regional settings on your site). So in that case use semicolon(`;`) instead of comma(`,`).

**Official Documentations**:

1. [Calculated Field Formulas](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/bb862071(v%3Doffice.14)).
2. [IF function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/if-function-7025be14-5665-43d0-af20-8293d1fe9d3a).